# Identifying and Removing a Subfloor in a 12-Year-Old UK House

Tags: flooring, subfloor, materials

I've recently purchased a 12-year-old house in England and am addressing a creaky spot on the first floor, which I suspect is related to a joist issue. Upon removing the carpet and underlay, I discovered a type of subfloor that's unfamiliar to me.

The boards appear to be glued together, and there might also be glue attaching them to the joists beneath. Unlike the typical plywood or OSB boards I'm used to, which are often nailed or screwed down, these have a layer that resembles fiberglass on top.

I've attached a picture for reference. My goal is to remove one board to inspect the joists underneath, but I'm cautious about potential damage and want to ensure I can source a replacement if necessary.

Has anyone encountered this type of subfloor? Can you help identify it and suggest the best removal approach?

[image]

Edit: found a spot in a different room where the boards have some space between them. It looks like particle board with fibreglass layer on top. 25 mm thickness all together. Will screw them to the creaky joist using 60 mm long 5 mm diameter countersunk wood screws and hope that this fixes the issue. If not I'll remove the board and inspect further.[image]

Comment: Could be some kind of floor leveler compound?

Comment: Could be a sound dampening layer. Is that stuff soft? If so, then consider scraping a band of the stuff off over the top of a joist to discover any fasteners. A strong magnet is less invasive and should work if that layer is thin enough and fastener material cooperates.

Comment: They're not tongue and groove? What makes you think that the boards are glued together?

Comment: @popham i've had a closer look and found some places where the subfloor boards don't fit together as well and the adhesive between them has disappeared. I managed to get a good look at the subfloor board and it is flat on the side with a thickness of 25 mm (no tongue and groove). I can see that in all other places there is something resembling construction adhesive holding the boards together. 
I think the next step is going to be using a stud finder to locate the joist that creaks and then using screws to make sure the subfloor board is firmly attached to it.